# Chamar complete() dentro do success()

Tags: javascript, ajax

Considere meu codigo ajax abaixo

```
function update(){
   $.ajax({
       url  : 'my.hrl',
       type : 'get',
       dataType : 'json',
       success : funcion(data){

           if(data.id == null){
               //chamar. complete ou error
            }

        },
       complete : function(){ 
          setInterval()
       }
   });
}
```

Existe uma forma de eu chamar o complete ou error, dentro do success, caso algum valor não venha do jeito que eu quero tipo nulo ou undefined?

[**EDIT 1**]
Era que eu gostaria que só atualizasse novamente a função só apenas quando a requisição estivesse completada após 3 segundos.

Caso o valor desse nulo ele também só tentaria depois de 3 segundos

Comment: O Complete será executado apenas após o success ser executado.  Ou seja isso que você quer não é possível. Você poderia criar uma função que possa chamar no complete e no success. Talvez se você detalhar mais o seu problema fique melhor para te da uma resposta.

Comment: Apenas uma observação, o `success` e `error` estão obsoletos e foram trocados por `done` e `fail` em versões mais recentes do JQuery

Comment: você pode abstrair a um outra função e chamar esta mesma função dentro das outras 3

Comment: Crie uma função fora e chame dentro dos dois métodos!

Comment: Tipo o php que no try catch se nao cair dentro do try eu posso dar um `throw new` para ir para o catch